# How to import an Xcode project from GitHub into my Xcode project?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, github, xcode-project

I downloaded the [DFURTSPPlayer Xcode project from GitHub](https://github.com/durfu/DFURTSPPlayer) but I could not import it into my Xcode project in any way.

I tried to simply drag the xcodeproj file into my project but I couldn't use it. It's like they are 2 separates projects that can't communicate with each other.

How can I do this?

[image: Xcode files]

Answer (score 0):

The project is an example project so you don’t want to include it all. If you have your own project and want to use DFURTSPPlayer then drag the `FFMpegiOS` and `FFMpegDecoder` folders into your project. Then look at the `DFUViewController` files to see how to use it.

Bare in mind there has been no code changes for 4 years on that project so it may not work still.